# Set of DAG vertices disconnecting a vertex from forbidden vertices

Tags: terminology, dag, minimum-cuts

Let $v$ be a vertex with in-degree 0 in an (acyclic) DAG $G$, and let $F$ be a subset of $G$'s vertices (the "forbidden") vertices. Now suppose $U$ is a set of vertices such that every path from $v$ to $F$ intersects $U$.

Is there a commonly-used term for such sets? I was thinking about using the term "Front", but a (cursory and lazy) search tells me that's not a popular term. I can't use "cut", because that's reserved for sets of *edges* with the similar property (cutting off $v$ from $F$; usually $F$ is the subgraph of all vertices reachable from $A$ but not in $A$).

Also, suppose that $U$ is minimal, in the sense that for every $u$ in $U$, there's a path from $v$ to $F$ which intersects no other vertex of $U$. Is there a commony-used term for *this* kind of sets?

If it helps, I'm willing to refer to $v$ as a "source" and to $F$ as the set of "sinks".

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_separator) that, for an undirected graph, you can say:

- $A$ is the **vertex separator** for $v$ and $F$.
- $A$ is the **separating set** for $v$ and $F$.
- $A$ is the **vertex cut** for $v$ and $F$.

perhaps these terms are used for digraphs as well, even though "connected components" are not quite the same thing in digraphs.

**edit:**  @PålGD suggests the variant "separator", similar to the second option.

Comment: Yes, $U$ is a $v-F$ separator!

Comment: @PålGD: I'm asking whether this term is used often, not whether it fits... can you say a few words about where/when it has been used?

Comment: Yes, _separator_ is standard terminology for a vertex set that breaks a graph into several components, and a $u-v$ separator is a vertex set that removes (hits) all paths from $u$ to $v$. A cut is more often used when the set you remove is a set of edges, e.g. maxflow/mincut.